# MVC cold startup not connecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

Notice how I say not connecting rather than just being slow.

This has been very difficult to reproduce, I am yet to get it to happen consistently and even went to far as to move the application on to a fresh machine thinking it was hardware related but alas, new machine - same issue.

Some captures with Fiddler seems to indicate that the connection is never completed.

Any suggestions on further investigative measures?

Apologies in advance for the vagueness of the question, I am just at a loss.

Comment: Breakpoint `Global.asax Application_Start`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you instrument it from the IIS side? Request tracing could tell you if something is taking so long that the request times out before it returns . . .

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to connect via HTTPS? I've had issues in the past when trying to run on my local box and I initiate a HTTPS connection which isn't supported by cassini. When a HTTPS connection fails it's not always obvious why.